# Bootstrap - Overlapping Columns and Rows

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website and using Bootstrap to simplify making the website responsive. The problem I am having is that I cannot find out how to allow images from one column or row to overlap other rows or columns. Usually without using bootstrap I would be using -margin or -padding to allow divs to appear on top of each other however Bootstrap will not allow me to use these tags and overwrites them when I use them.

```
<div class="row row7">
<div class="col-lg-1"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6"><img src="/images/map.png"></a></div>
<div class="col-lg-3"><img src="/images/map2.png"></div>
<div class="col-lg-2"></div>
</div>
```

I need the map image to finish in column 7 and map2 images to start in column 7

Thanks in advance,

Andi

Comment: Have you tried nesting rows?

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Apologies, I am trying to be as clear as possible without actually copying an image of the website I am building from design. I need the images map and map2 to sit beside each other in the row. I need the map1 image to span from column 2 and into column 7, I need map 2 to span starting in column 7 to column 10.

Comment: Create a fiddle or [Bootply](http://bootply.com/new) that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `.col-push-xx-x` and `.col-pull-xx-x` classes.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-1" style="background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2)">
        [Image 1]
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2)">
        [Image 2]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks soo much, i've been searching and not realising the push pull feature of Bootstrap. While i'm talking to someone who can decode my ramblings, what is the best way to position elements using Bootstrap padding and % or what is best practice? Thanks again.